# Understand the bullet (5.4.1) in [dcl.init.ref] clause

Tags: c++, reference, language-lawyer

Given the following example,

```
struct S 
{ 
    operator const double&();
}

const int& ref = S();
```

First per [dcl.init.ref]/5:

> A reference to type “`cv1 T1`” is initialized by an expression of type
> “`cv2 T2`” as follows:

Taking "*cv1* `T1`" as `const int` and "*cv2* `T2`" as `S`.

Skipping all discarded bullets until we reach to [dcl.init.ref]/(5.4) which says:

> (5.4) Otherwise:
>
> - (5.4.1) If `T1` or `T2` is a class type and `T1` is not reference-related to `T2`, user-defined conversions are considered using the rules for
>   copy-initialization of an object of type “`cv1 T1`” by user-defined
>   conversion ([dcl.init], [over.match.copy], [over.match.conv]); the program is ill-formed if the corresponding non-reference copy-initialization would be ill-formed. The result of the call to the conversion function, as described for the non-reference copy-initialization, is then used to direct-initialize the reference. For this direct-initialization, user-defined conversions are not considered.
> - (5.4.2) [..]

I think all we're agree on that this bullet (5.4.1) is one satisfied because `T2` is a class type, and `T1` is not reference-related to `T2`. But my problem at this point is that I can't understand the rest of the wording, and how it's related to each other.

Given the first sentence: "*If `T1` or `T2` is a class type and `T1` is not reference-related to `T2`, **user-defined conversions are considered using the rules for copy-initialization of an object of type “`cv1 T1`” by user-defined conversion***" What's the intention of the bold part? And the entity being initialized is "lvalue reference to *cv1* `T1`" **not** an object of type "*cv1* `T1`". So why the word "object" is mentioned here? Also, what're those rules of "copy-initialization"?

Given the second sentence: "*The result of the call to the conversion function, as described for the non-reference copy-initialization, is then used to direct-initialize the reference.*". Does this mean that we have to go back again to the beginning of [dcl.init.ref]/5? and why?

The last thing I need to understand is that the reference being initialized is of type `const int&`, and the called conversion function returns `const double&`; so how `ref` can bind to `const double` which is of an unrelated type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If `T1` or `T2` is a class type and `T1` is not reference-related to `T2`, user-defined conversions are considered using the rules for copy-initialization of an object of type "*cv1* `T1`" by user-defined conversion

As it says, you *use the rules* for copy-initialization of an object (not reference) of type *cv1* `T1`. In other words, you pretend that the thing you have to initialize is an object, not reference, and you figure out how to perform such an initialization (treated as a copy-initialization, not a direct-initialization). The rules for copy-initialization of objects are found in [[dcl.init.general]/16](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.general#16). In this case, you will reach p16.7:

> Otherwise, if the source type is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type, conversion functions are considered. The applicable conversion functions are enumerated ([over.match.conv]), and the best one is chosen through overload resolution ([over.match]). The user-defined conversion so selected is called to convert the initializer expression into the object being initialized.
> If the conversion cannot be done or is ambiguous, the initialization is ill-formed.

[over.match.conv] explains how to determine the candidate conversion functions. Clearly, in this case there is only one candidate. The conversion sequence required to initialize an object of type `const int` from `S()` would be calling the conversion function `S::operator const double&`, followed by an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, and finally a floating-integral conversion.

After [over.match] has been applied to choose the best conversion function, we go back to [dcl.init.ref]/5.4.1:

> The result of the call to the conversion function, as described for the non-reference copy-initialization, is then used to direct-initialize the reference.

Now, here's the subtlety: we look at the hypothetical conversion sequence that would have occurred if we were initializing an object of type `const int`, but we do not actually initialize an object of type `const int`. Instead, we only call the conversion function, `S::operator const double&`, and we ignore the rest of the hypothetical conversion sequence. With the result of the conversion function, which is an lvalue of type `const double`, we direct-initialize our reference from this value.

To determine how to perform this direct-initialization, we have to go back to the beginning of [dcl.init.ref]/5, but in order to avoid potential recursion, it is specified that user-defined conversions will not be considered during this second round. In this case [dcl.init.ref]/5.4.2 will be reached in the second round:

> Otherwise, the initializer expression is implicitly converted to a prvalue of type "`T1`". The temporary materialization conversion is applied, considering the type of the prvalue to be "*cv1* `T1`", and the reference is bound to the result.

This is where the temporary materialization conversion that you were wondering about is specified.

Comment: @John As it says, it is "considered to yield X for this process of selecting candidate functions". For that purpose (namely enumerating candidates for overload resolution) and that purpose only, the conversion function returning "reference to `X`" is considered to yield `X`.

Comment: @John I hope this addressed the issue in your second comment, which I wasn't really able to understand.

Comment: `operator const double&` has suddenly become `operator const int&` in the second part of the answer

Comment: @LanguageLawyer - _"operator const double& has suddenly become operator const int& in the second part of the answer"_ Are you have something to say about how this happens?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer - Specifically, I can't understand this answer starting from _"After [over.match] has been applied to choose the best conversion function, we go back to [dcl.init.ref]/5.4.1"_

Comment: @LanguageLawyer - Can you correct this «typo»?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer - Feel free to write another answer to the question anytime you have a time. And I apologize again if I misjudged you. The answer really makes me overthink.

Comment: @John The typo has been fixed

Comment: @John If there is something in particular that you don't understand (e.g., why is it that we have to go back to [dcl.init.ref]/5.4.1) please say so and I will try to explain. If the entire answer is hard to understand because English is not your first language, I would suggest you ask your question on a website where answers will be in your native language.

Comment: _"To determine how to perform this direct-initialization, we have to go back to the beginning of [dcl.init.ref]/5"_ What made you jump/redirect to the beginning of [dcl.init.ref]/5? And in the second round (where user-defined conversions are not considered) how (5.4.2) would be applicable (the initializer expression has to be converted to `const int` even though the user-defined conversion is not considered)?

Comment: _If the entire answer is hard to understand because English is not your first language, I would suggest you ask your question on a website where answers will be in your native language_ Not really, just because the wording of the standard itself is difficult at least for me. I am still relatively good in English, but not so good :)

Comment: _The typo has been fixed_ Why not completely?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer thanks, hopefully it's fixed for real this time.

Comment: @John The reason why "we have to go back to the beginning of [dcl.init.ref]/5" is that that is the section of the standard that explains how to initialize a reference. The rules we have followed up to this point tell us that the problem has been reduced from the original one (initializing `const int&` from prvalue of `S`) to a new one (initializing `const int&` from lvalue of `const double`).

Comment: @John In the second round, 5.4.2 is applicable because all preceding points are not applicable in the problem at hand (initialization of a `const int&` from lvalue of `const double`).

Comment: _" In the second round, 5.4.2 is applicable because all preceding points are not applicable in the problem at hand (initialization of a const int& from **lvalue of const double**)"_ Do you mean that we have reached 5.4.2 with initializer expression `const double lvalue` not with `S()`? This is originally what I asked you about the first time.

Comment: @John Yes, that's exactly what I mean. Please see my comment immediately preceding the one that you have quoted from.

Comment: So as far as I understood there's no need to say _"but in order to avoid potential recursion, **it is specified that user-defined conversions will not be considered during this second round**"_, because in the second round there is no user-defined/class types are involved. You just have an entity being initialzied of type `const int&` and initialzier of type `const double`; no user-defined types in this second round are involved

Comment: @John In this particular case, there is indeed no need for that rule for the reason you say. In a different case, that rule might help prevent recursion. (please post a separate question if you want to ask more about this particular point). I have only mentioned it because you included that part in your question. It is not relevant to this particular initialization.